# Do photons interact with everything?

Tags: particle-physics

Suppose you shoot a beam of photons in a particle collider. Are there any particles in which the photons do not interact with?

Q2: What is an interaction between particles?

Comment: Sure, photons don't interact with other photons, at least not directly. They also don't interact with any particles which have zero charge.

Comment: @DanielSank are we including interactions via gravity in that list?

Comment: @daniel So if you shot a beam of electron neutrinos, or any other particles with 0 net charge, into a beam of photons, the energy of the system would not change at all (is this how one can tell if an interaction occurs?)?

Comment: @colour not zero net charge. Just zero charge on any particles. A neutron still interacts with photons because its constituents have charge

Comment: @Jim can you give an example of a particle with zero charge?

Comment: Photons don't interact with neutrinos.  Neutrinos are also particles with zero charge.

Photons do not seem to interact with dark matter either.

Comment: Photons, neutrinos, gluons, Z bosons and Higgs bosons. Though photons photons may interact with all these at second order.

Comment: Dark matter is conjectured not to interact with photons. I used "conjectured" because physicists are currently clueless regarding the nature of dark matter.

Comment: @DanielSank How photons do not interact with uncharged particles? If you direct a laser beam on a incoming neutron, the neutron will not slowed down?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler A neutron is composed of charged quarks. It has zero net charge, but so do most atoms and molecules, which light interacts with at the sub-level.

Answer (score -1):

An interaction between to particles is mediated by a gauge boson like photons, gluons, W/Z bosons, and the theoretical graviton. Any charged particle interacts with each other through virtual photons, so yes photons interact with particles. To be specific they interact with particle that are charged.

Comment: What do you mean by 'mediated'? What leads us to conclude this?

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg/300px-Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg.png

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_carrier